# Add Roles dynamically in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, roles

I have a question about Symfony2, I Hope someone could help me.

I'm developing an application where the Administrator user has to be able to create new roles with new privileges. In other words, the app/security.yml file will change every time the Administrator creates a new role. I'd like to know how I can do that... or if there is a Bundle that could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [ACL's](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html).

But it depends on what you are doing with the roles. Why is the Admin creating new Roles? What permissions do they grant? The Roles typically protect routes, and I don't know a way to dynamically define routes from some sort of Admin interface (out of the box). So I'm guessing you want to give users permissions to do various things. So I *think* you want to look at ACL's.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own user entity extends UserInterface and then custom the function getRoles();

Take a look at http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!... I'm going to take a look at the link